# When using the Date or Timesense format in columns.yaml date is not reflecting the correct date information

Tags: octobercms, october-partial

I have a problem with backend lists not rendering the correct date time, and is ahead of the actual DB value of the model by 5 hours:

Here is my configuration:

Server TZ: America/Toronto

OctoberCMS timezone=>America/Toronto (config/app.php)

Here is the result for the following formats in Columns.yaml (have confirmed the Database holds the correct time and that the model has the correct time, this is a presentation issue):

```
text: 2016-12-15 10:52:31   

Datetime: Thu, Dec 15, 2016 3:52 PM

timetense: Today at 3:52 PM
```

Is there something im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question was found by READING ABOUT UTC and talking to the guys at OctoberCMS.

Keep the timezone in the app.php file set to UTC to ensure integrity, of your timestamps.

Set your user timezone in the OctoberCMS application on the backend tools.

More details on the "Why" can be found here
http://www.camroncade.com/managing-timezones-with-laravel/

Comment: Thank you for your research. It was helpful for me, too. :)